# How to get interface to C# object wrapped in COM, from MFC DLL

Tags: c#, c++, interface, com

I have C# object in a DLL.
I call a method of this object via COM from MFC DLL. like this:

```
BOOL CForwarder::InitMyManagedFlex()
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    IForwarderPtr pIFwd(__uuidof(MyForwarder));

    long lResult = 0;
    VARIANT_BOOL ret = FALSE;
    BSTR bstr = AsciiToBSTR("AAA");

    // Call the Add method.
    pIFwd->Start(bstr, &ret);

    SysFreeString(bstr);

    wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", ret);

    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();

    return (ret == VARIANT_TRUE) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Then after a while I call another method SetTimeFormat in exactly the same manner.
The problem is that every time I call in this manner I instantiate a new C# object, but in fact I am trying to reach the same object that was created the first time and simply set one of its properties to a different value.

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
IForwarderPtr pIFwd(__uuidof(MyForwarder));
```

So how do I get the interface to the same C# object instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the interface pointer.
IForwarderPtr pIFwd(__uuidof(MyForwarder));
```

Actually that line does two things.  It creates the COM object whose UUID/ClassID is `MyForwarder` **and** stores the result in `pIFwd`.

If you don't want to create it each time try this:

```
IForwarderPtr pIFwd(__uuidof(MyForwarder));
pIFwd->Start(bstr, &ret);
.
.
.
.
pIFwd->SetTimeFormat (....)

.
.
.
SysFreeString(bstr);

wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", ret);

// Uninitialize COM.
CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: I know - but as I mentioned SetTimeFormat is coming as a totally separated call from MFC DLL

Comment: @LeonHavin Then stick it in a class member/global or something

Answer (score 0):

You can move the following statements to your constructor

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
_pIFwd(__uuidof(MyForwarder)); //where _pIFwd is a member variable of your class
```

& the statement *CoUninitialize()* to your destructor. 
Add *IForwardPtr* as a member variable of your class.

This way you will be able to re-use the same instance.

Comment: when I move this to constructor  pIFwd(__uuidof(MyFlexForwarder)); and also make IFlexForwarderPtr pIFwd member of a class then
it says: "Error - call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator () or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type"

Comment: In addition if I add in the constructor
IForwarderPtr pIFwd(__uuidof(MyForwarder));
mpIFwd = pIFwd

and then add IForwarderPtr mpIFwd as member of a class then it claims every occurrence of mpIFwd in the code as undeclared identifier...

Comment: Do you have a header file for the IForwarderPtr interface?

Comment: Use forward declaration `class IFowarderPtr;` in your CForwarder header file. Declare your member variable as `IFowarderPtr *mPIFwd;`

Comment: I have Forwarder.h and that's where I declared IForwarderPtr mpIFwd, and also before that declare class IForwarderPtr. but then in Forwarder.cpp (where also IForwarder definition and implementation lives, any occurrence of mpIFwd is marked as unknown identifiyer...

Comment: You have a `#import "<your.tlb>" no_namespace raw_interfaces_only` in your .cpp file right? Move this to the header file. No need of the forward class declaration. I tried this & worked for me. In my header file I used the `#import "MyDll.tlb"` & defined the member variable as `IMyClassPtr _ptr;`. In my constructor I used the statements `HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
IMyClassPtr ptr(__uuidof(MyClass));
_ptr = ptr;`. This worked for me. I could use the interface across calls.